# How to prevent multi-homed clients from overwriting their own DNS entries

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-7, wifi, reverse-dns

Most of the computers on our network are laptops, so they have two adapters: wired and wireless. When a laptop is connected to both wired and wireless networks, it registers both IP  addresses in DNS. The reverse lookup zones have an entry for each address, as expected.

However, the forward lookup zone has only one entry for the hostname, which can be either the wired or wireless IP address. This is troublesome because when I access the laptops remotely, I always want to use the wired connection if available, but resolving DNS sometimes give me the wireless IP.

What is the best way to resolve this problem? I suspect that it has something to do with setting up another forward lookup zone, but I'm not really sure about what details are involved.

*Note: I recently converted our WLAN to use a different subnet, so I noticed the problem when I looked through the forward lookup zone and saw IP's from different subnets. I think this problem has existed for a long time, and I just finally noticed it.*

Comment: Is it normal to have a separate DNS zone for wireless clients?

Comment: No, it isn't...

Answer (score 2):

Configure the Advanced TCP/IP DNS settings of the wireless NIC to not register in DNS.

Comment: Can this be set anywhere in group policy? Or does each computer need to be manually updated?

Comment: Good question. I don't have the answer to that.